# PDF report engine or HTML5?

Tags: html, pdf

I would like to make a web-based application that exports some statistics/reports from our database.

What are the pros and cons of choosing HTML5/CSS goodies (e.g. Google Chart tools) over a PDF report engine (e.g. FastReport)?

For instance:

HTML5/CSS: no need for extra server/engine (load in general) that manages the form templates and the data. Also no need for the end user browser to load a PDF.

Comment: I think if you would you like to present the report to the web audience (online) the CSS approach would be more handy and visually appealing. If you would like to present offline the pdf could be another choice.

Comment: both are for offline use as they are both printable.

Comment: Then definitely i'll opting for pdf. There are some inconsistencies in how `@media print` are interpreted between different browser vendors.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS is a good alternative - i use it to generate PDF reports from HTML5/CSS, server side of course. Of course, your end user would have to download the PDF, but you can show the HTML on an iframe and a "download as pdf" button below. All modern desktop browsers support PDF viewing without any external bloatware (e.g. adobe reader et al)
http://phantomjs.org/

More on this: https://aboullaite.me/phantomjs-generate-pixel-perfect-pdf-reports/